# Is it possible to tell what source loaded a Linux kernel module?

Tags: linux, drivers, kernel-modules, init-script

In my Linux distribution there are a number of modules loaded during boot up and I'm trying to find where they're loaded from.

```
[root /proc]# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
bufferclass_ti          5409  0
omaplfb                11525  0
musb_dsps               6444  0
musb_hdrc              52530  1 musb_dsps
pvrsrvkm              174837  2 bufferclass_ti,omaplfb
c_can_platform          4172  0
c_can                   8180  1 c_can_platform
can_dev                 6951  1 c_can
musb_am335x             1199  0
```

By searching in `/etc/init.d` I can see the scripts which load the USB and frame buffer modules:

```
[root /etc/init.d]# grep -rsI "modprobe" *
loadusb.sh:modprobe musb_hdrc
loadusb.sh:modprobe musb_am335x
loadusb.sh:modprobe musb_dsps
pvr-init:       modprobe omaplfb
pvr-init:       modprobe bufferclass_ti
```

But I can't seem to find where the CAN modules are loaded from. There is no `/etc/modules` or `/etc/modules.conf` on this platform, and I've searched `/etc/` for `modprobe`/`insmod`/`c_can` but no luck. In the `dmesg` I can see the CAN driver kicking off:

```
[    3.745933] CAN device driver interface
[    3.891592] c_can_platform 481cc000.d_can: c_can_platform device registered (
regs=fa1cc000, irq=68)
```

But I don't know what script loaded it. Is there any further information/logs I can dig up to help identify what put the CAN modules into the system?

---

some info from `modinfo` and `/sys/devices`:

```
[root /etc/udev/rules.d]# modinfo c_can
filename:       /lib/modules/3.12.103.12-am335xpsp-TMKv1.03.02R/kernel/drivers/net/can/c_can/c_can.ko
description:    CAN bus driver for Bosch C_CAN controller
license:        GPL v2
author:         Bhupesh Sharma <bhupesh.sharma@st.com>
srcversion:     692B302E87FD3333EF840FE
depends:        can-dev
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.12.103.12-am335xpsp-TMKv1.03.02R mod_unload modversions ARMv6 p2v8
[root /etc/udev/rules.d]# modinfo can_dev
filename:       /lib/modules/3.12.103.12-am335xpsp-TMKv1.03.02R/kernel/drivers/net/can/can-dev.ko
alias:          rtnl-link-can
author:         Wolfgang Grandegger <wg@grandegger.com>
license:        GPL v2
description:    CAN device driver interface
srcversion:     65FA84AFE987C1155CF95A1
depends:
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.12.103.12-am335xpsp-TMKv1.03.02R mod_unload modversions ARMv6 p2v8
[root /]# modinfo c_can_platform
filename:       /lib/modules/3.12.103.12-am335xpsp-TMKv1.03.02R/kernel/drivers/net/can/c_can/c_can_platform.ko
description:    Platform CAN bus driver for Bosch C_CAN controller
license:        GPL v2
author:         Bhupesh Sharma <bhupesh.sharma@st.com>
srcversion:     DA1DCA3FBA7E75E459BDCEC
alias:          platform:d_can
alias:          platform:c_can
alias:          platform:c_can_platform
alias:          of:N*T*Cbosch,d_can*
alias:          of:N*T*Cbosch,c_can*
depends:        c_can
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.12.103.12-am335xpsp-TMKv1.03.02R mod_unload modversions ARMv6 p2v8
[root /sys/devices]# ls
44e10800.pinmux   fixedregulator.3  platform          software
backlight.4       ocp.2             soc.0             system
breakpoint        panel.5           soc0              virtual
```

Comment: could be by udev?  can't quite think of a good test.  Maybe `modinfo` shows a modalias that matches one of the modalias files you can find in /sys/devices.  if no modalias shown then probably not.

Comment: @sourcejedi - I dumped some info. Looks like `c_can` doesn't have an alias listed but has a dependency on `can_dev`. `can_dev` has an alias of `rtnl-link-can` but I don't see anything matching that in `/sys/devices`. I also checked `/etc/udev` for any other rules but the only entries are for touchscreen and Ethernet, nothing for CAN

Comment: Check initramfs or similar for your distro, that could load lot of modules

Comment: @VenkatC - Not sure if my distro supports initramfs. Do you have a good way to check? It's not listed in `/proc/filesystems`, and when I check my defconfig I see `CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE=""`, not sure what that means yet I'll have to look it up but empty strings aren't normally promising.

Comment: check dmesg.  If there's an init-thingy it should say like `[    0.404592] Unpacking initramfs...
[    1.021297] Freeing initrd memory: 18764K (ffff880035b4a000 - ffff880036d9d000)`

Comment: ok rtnl-link-can won't be in /sys/devices, it's not the normal udev coldplug.  that modalias must be to do with netlink sockets...  basically if you ran some program that tries to configure a CAN bus in a certain way it would load that module.

Comment: I think `c_can_platform` is loaded first - going by "used by" in lsmod output.  So that's what you want to check for aliases rather than `c_can`.

Comment: @sourcejedi - I think you're on to something. I checked the `c_can_platform` and I see more aliases in there (see new edit), they're prefixed with `of:` and `platform:`, searching around a bit I found a script in `/etc/init.d/udev` which mentions platform devices, but my understanding of this line is "not to do anything when I platform device is added": ` --subsystem-nomatch=platform`

Comment: I apologize for my vagueness.  It could be the `of:` alias.  OpenFirmware, right?  udev finds something exposed by the firmware, somewhere under sysfs, with a matching modalias file.  It effectively runs `modprobe` with the contents of that modalias file.  (In new versions of udev, it uses libkmod).  This is the same process e.g. how usb-storage is loaded when you plug in a USB stick.  The udev initscript scans all devices in sys at boot, which is called "coldplug" because it's not quite "hotplug".

Comment: I don't particularly understand why the nomatch platform option is there btw.  Might be some policy from the udev developers, telling kernel devs they were doing something the wrong way (by breaking the pattern they used).

Answer (score 1):

As per my current understanding. No one (user space script) is actually calling `modprobe`\ `insmod` to get these CAN drivers inserted, this is because they are [Platform Devices](https://lwn.net/Articles/448502/).

This is identified by:

1. The `alias:          platform:` information from the modinfo
   command
2. The source code for the c_can_platform which defines the `c_can_plat_driver` as a `platform_driver`:

The platform drivers are registered as such in the code then as part of the Linux kernel startup procedure the list of platform drivers are inserted/started.

I need to find more concrete evidence/documentation of this, but this makes sense to me right now so I'll place it as an answer.